# Find the equation of the hyperbolic line through $A=(3,4)$, perpendicular to hyperbolic line $x^2+y^2=25$, $ y>0$

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

I don't know how to solve this exercise in Hyperbolic Geometry.

> Find the linear equation of hyperbolic line which passes through point $A=(3,4)$ and it is perpendicular to hyperbolic line with linear equation $x^2+y^2=25$  , $ y>0$.

Comment: To be clear: Is this an exercise in the Upper Half-Plane Model?

Comment: @Blue yes it is

Comment: @Blue Can you help me?

Comment: Since $A$ is on the given circle, the perpendicular "line" needed is the *orthogonal circle* through $A$. A neat thing about orthogonal circles: *Where they meet, the tangent line to one circle passes through the center of the other.* And, here, you know that the center of the target circle is on the $x$-axis. So, figure out where the tangent at $A$ meets the $x$-axis (recall that the tangent at a point is perpendicular to the radius to the point), and you'll have the center of the target circle; the distance from $A$ to that center gives you the radius; from there you can get the equation.